# Is there a monitor stand for 2 monitors that can rotate together?

Tags: monitor-stand

[image: Rotation Requirements]

Normally, I write code, browse webpages, and read documents with my monitors in a vertical rotation (portrait rather than landscape), but I've come to realize when I play games or watch shows (which I typically do at the same time), it's better to do it in a horizontal rotation.

I want a monitor stand that can hold two monitors together and rotate around a central axis. In my diagram, I show a red base connected to a green central rotation. That connects to the black bar which rotates both monitors attached via the blue brackets.

The main idea here is to switch from coding to games, I would just have to rotate 1 object together. The blue connectors should be able to move along the black bar to some degree to adjust for monitor size, and provide a way to adjust the angle in. The green rotation should just rotate the monitor on the roll axis.

I've looked for a solution, but the closest I can find is this:
[Planar Dual Monitor by Lenovo](http://www3.lenovo.com/us/en/accessories/monitor-accessories/monitor-stands-and-arms/Planar-Dual-Monitor-stand/p/78001319?cid=us:cse:KWey90:ca|Bing|78001319&CAWELAID=600003960000034039&ef_id=WXD-aQAAAGXuFnPP:20170807192240:s), but it doesn't rotate around the central axis.

Does anyone have a monitor set up like this? I'm not afraid of combining two monitor stands together if I must (like combine a single stand with the Lenovo bar), but I'd prefer a solution I can just buy.

Secondary reqs:
24" monitors in 1920x1200 configuration